# Getting SSL certificate error after changing computer date

Tags: google-chrome, ssl-certificate

I recently changed my computer date for some reason (I'm back in the past ..) and I can no longer go on any website that use SSL certificate with Google Chrome, how can I bypass the fact that the certificate is not valid ? (The dates are in the future ...)

Comment: This is so annoying, I should be able to set whatever date I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nature of SSL certificates is that they are valid FROM a certain date and time, UNTIL a certain date and time. If you change the date and time on your computer and then go onto an SSL enabled site (HTTPS) the browser will obtain the certificate and compare the date and time it knows (your system's clock) against what the certificate says. If they are out by even a few minutes the browser goes "Are you sure you want to trust the identity of this site?" because it can only go on what is presented to it.

This is why it is vital that your computer date and time are correct to the nearest minute (if you can) to a trustworthy time source for your locale (your city/country).

Comment: How can I have a valid certificate even if my system date/time is in the past ? I can't put it back to normal for now but I also really need Google which is blocked because of this error

Comment: You can't. The certificate isn't provided by you. Your browser should have an option where you can continue onto the site you're requesting but you accept that the site cannot be trusted...?

Comment: No I can't it just tell me that the certificate is not valid and block me there, no bypass button

Comment: You could try a different browser (Chrome, maybe). If that fails then you're stuck. Ideally you shouldn't ever have a need to set your computer clock to a historic time. The only reason I can think of is to be able to re-run trial software...

Comment: I got my system date to the start date of the certificate so it work, we are waiting to receive a license right now, but the projects got to move so, yeah... Thanks for the help.